# URL Masking is not working using prettyfaces jar

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, prettyfaces

web.xml

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
   <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> 
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

WEB-INF/pretty-cofig.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0 
           http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd">   
<url-mapping id="errorPage">
    <pattern value="/test/new"/>
    <view-id value="/faces/test/mynewtest.xhtml"/>       
</url-mapping>
```

I have added this above code for url marking in my application and additionally i added prettyfaces jar also.
After added this, i have started my tomcat server and prettyfaces also started.
While hitting this particular url "/faces/test/mynewtest.xhtml" , the url is not masking into "/test/new". 
Please provide the suggestion to work properly.

Comment: Can you please help,how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The idea of PrettyFaces is not to "mask" the URL but to support pretty RESTful URLs including path parameters and similar concepts. So if you request "/test/new" and get your page rendered correctly, PrettyFaces is working as expected.